# Is there an elegant way to dynamically generate a query based on the values of a list?

Tags: loops, coldfusion

I've created this code blow that works and does what I want it to do, however I was wondering if there is a better smarter way to do this. Here is the code:

```
<cfset myList = ValueList(qSeminarWisReg.SeminarWisTitle,",")>

<cfif ListLen(myList,",") lte 1>
  <cfquery datasource="#APPLICATION.dataSource#" name="qSeminarWisRegTwo">
  SELECT * FROM SeminarWis
  WHERE SeminarWisID = <cfqueryparam value="#myList#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
  </cfquery>
<cfelse>
  <cfquery datasource="#APPLICATION.dataSource#" name="qSeminarWisRegTwo">
  SELECT * FROM SeminarWis
  WHERE 0 = 0
    AND (SeminarWisID  = <cfqueryparam value="100000000" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
    <cfloop index = "x" list = "#myList#" delimiters = ","> OR SeminarWisID  = #x#</cfloop>)
  </cfquery>
</cfif>
```

Basically I have a dynamically generated list, which has numbers in it, delimited by a comma. Now these numbers correspond to Unique Keys in a table, so then I'm just dynamically grabbing all the rows the user wants.

Like I said, this works, but if anyone has any tips on how to make this better let me know! The part that bothers me is that I have to use the "1000000" value (one that doesn't exist) before i can get into the OR statements.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you want to use CFQUERYPARAM with list="true" and the IN operator:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   SeminarWis
WHERE  SeminarWisID IN ( 
          <cfqueryparam value="#myList#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" list="true" /> 
       )
```

Note that this will only work if listLen(myList) GTE 1

Comment: That's beautiful and works! I didn't even know about the "list" attribute in cfqueryparam! And the "IN" statement is what I waned, but didn't even know what I was looking for! Thanks! Great answer.